# Master Detail relationship with two related models in emberjs

Tags: ember.js

I have two models, Videos belong to a category. A category has many videos.  I have a list of categories on my home route. When you click on one of the categories you are transitioned to the category route which displays a list of categories on the left in the categories.hbs and the videos for that category in category.hbs So the categories route is the master and category is the detail.

Here is my current router:

```
export default Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('home', { path: '/' }, function() {
  });

  this.resource('categories', { path: 'categories' }, function() {
    this.resource('category', { path: ':category_id' });
  });

  this.resource('videos', { path: 'videos' }, function() {
    this.resource('video', { path: ':video_id' });
  });

});
```

Here is my homepage route

application.js

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return this.store.find('category');
    }
});
```

Homepage Template

home.hbs

```
<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="btn-group-vertical" role="group" aria-label="...">
 {{#each category in model}}
    {{#link-to 'category' category}}<img src="{{category.photo}}" />{{/link-to}} 
 {{/each}}
</div>
</div>
```

Here are the other routes

categories.js

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return this.store.find('category');
    }
});
```

category.js

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
    return this.store.find('category', params.category_id);
  }
});
```

How do I set this up so that when you click on a category from the home page the first video in that category is displayed, and the other videos in the category are displayed in the sidebar, so that when you click on one of them it becomes the detail and the other videos in that category become the master?

So to clarify.. What I have now is list of categories is the master, all videos in selected category are the detail. What I need is all videos in category are the master, and first video in category OR selected video are the detail.

Comment: "...when you click on a category from the **home** page..." - you might want to show home route, controller and template.

Comment: Please create a demo with https://emberjs.jsbin.com/ Don't forget to include Ember Data. Use Mockjax for backend.

Comment: I added the homepage route and template, there is no controller. As far as the demo, I am brand new to emberjs and using ember cli, so Im not sure I could create the demo on emberjs.jsbin.com if I wanted to, but I can try.

Answer (score 0):

So here is what I arrived at thus far

my router now looks like this:

```
var Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  location: config.locationType
});

export default Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('home', { path: '/' }, function() {
    this.resource('show', { path: ':video_id' });
  });

  this.resource('categories', { path: 'categories' }, function() {
    this.resource('category', { path: ':category_id' }, function() {
        this.resource('vid', { path: ':video_id' });
    });

  });
```

So I now can click from the homepage to a category and get a sidebar with the videos from that category.

Here is the category.hbs

```
<div class="col-md-2">
 <h2>Category: {{name}}</h2>
  {{#each video in videos}}
    {{#link-to 'vid' video}}{{video.title}}{{/link-to}}<br />
  {{/each}}
 </div>

 {{outlet}}
```

So the problem I am left with is that unless I click on one of the videos on the left, the outlet is blank. How do I get the first video to show up regardless?

I have done some research and it seems i should be doing something along the lines of this:

```
afterModel: function(category, transition) {
    //code that transitions to the first video in category.videos using the vid route....
  }
```